# What is the name for a lateral band saw guide: one that guides wood forward at a set distance from the blade

Tags: bandsaw, guide

What is the name for a lateral band saw guide: one that guides wood forward at a set distance from the blade ?

I want to cut strips from a long flat strip of wood (ripping rather than a cross-cut)

Comment: I'm not sure I have the right idea. A fence or a sled?

Comment: One set of things I saw was an adjustable fence, which comes with nicer band saws. I think that is the simplest name for what I want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it is called `resaw fence` at [this site](http://www.woodworkingadvice.com/tools-reviews/stationary-tools/bandsaws/78-parts-of-a-bandsaw).

Comment: While the link backs up the assertion, you should include some of the details in your answer